# std::regex fails with g++?

Tags: regex, c++11

I'm trying to use C++11's regex for a very simple filtering task, but I couldn't make it to work like I want it. So I started to write a separate demonstration program.

The thing is that the simplest things fail miserably. For example:

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> inputs;
  inputs.push_back("1");
  inputs.push_back("123");
  inputs.push_back("a");
  inputs.push_back("apple");
  inputs.push_back(":apple3.worm");

  std::string pattern("[0-9]");
  std::regex r(pattern, std::regex_constants::grep);

  for(auto const &s: inputs)
  {
    bool ok = std::regex_match(s, r);
    std::cout << (ok?"POS":"NEG") << ": " << s << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled without warnings with `g++ -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -O3 rfail.cpp -o rfail`. Output:

```
POS: 1
NEG: 123
POS: a
NEG: apple
NEG: :apple3.worm
```

Same happend when I replace `[0-9]` with `[[:digit:]]`. What is happening? What do I do wrong?

Update:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

Comment: You should give us more informations about your `g++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [regex_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) doc carefuly, you'll notice that:

> **The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this function to return true** (i.e., without any additional characters before or after the match). For a function that returns true when the match is only part of the sequence, see regex_search.

Thus, if you want to check if your string contains at least 1 number, change your regex to `.*[0-9].*`

---

Note that I can't reproduce your output, mine is:

```
POS: 1
NEG: 123
NEG: a // <- here's the diff
NEG: apple
NEG: :apple3.worm
```

(compiled with `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`)

---

Given your version of gcc, it seems that it's running a highly experimental implementation of `<regex>` which has been included in `gcc 4.9` [more information about the bug here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631).

You should consider an update if you consider using regex within your code.

Comment: Why `[0-9]` matches `a`?

Comment: I get what you say about the full matching. My problem is that 3rd line in the output. I will update my post with the g++ version.